# Fullscreen button in html5 tag

Tags: iphone, html, ios

I'm writing a html5 page with a embedded video tag for iPad.
How can I hide or disable the fullscreen button? I just need to show the video without the fullscreen option.

Answer (score 2):

You could try removing the "controls" attribute on the video tag and create your own play/pause button(s).

http://webkit.org/blog/140/html5-media-support/